# Regularity of Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-analysis, matrix-inverse

Let $k\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$, let $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ be open, connected and let $G\in C^k(\Omega;\mathbb{R}^{n\times n})$ satisfy
 $$
 \operatorname*{rank}G(x)= \operatorname*{rank}G(y),\text{ for all }x,y\in\Omega.
 $$
 Then, is it true that the [Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse) $G^+ \in C^k(\Omega;\mathbb{R}^{n\times n})$?

The case $k=0$ case seems to be true (Penrose 1955). What about $k\in\mathbb{N}$? Could you please suggest a reference? Any help in this direction is welcome.

Comment: Just for clarity, is your $G^+$ defined by $G^+(\omega):=G(\omega)^+$ for all $\omega\in \Omega$?